# SocketActivityTrigger and pushNotifications

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, uwp

Why I need to check pushNotifications capability, when I use SocketActivityTrigger? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: because SocketActivityTrigger is mostly used for push notifications?

Comment: That's the answer?

Comment: We are trying to confirm this issue with someone who is familiar with this topic. It may take some time, as soon as I get the response, I will report here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

Push notification capability (`ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION`) is for Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight.

Both Windows Runtime 8.1 and UWP (Windows 10) do not have a push notifications capability, see the [list of all capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) in UWP.

If you check the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket/cs/SocketActivityStreamSocket/Package.appxmanifest#L58-L59) for SocketActivityTrigger, you'll see it only uses capabilities for internet connectivity.

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: But in msdn is: "If your app uses socket activity triggers, you must specify the pushNotifications capability in the app manifest."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/networking-basics?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 - line above Choosing a network trigger

Comment: So I don't need this capability?